# How to authenticate user, using the Google account user_id to third party socket server

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager

This tutorial was a grate help in understanding the `AccountManager` and `authToken`:
[***Nick's Blog Authenticating against App Engine from an Android app***](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app)

I still need to get that to work with a basic Java SSL/TSL socket server where for now
my Android users authenticates themselves with passwords.

*UPDATE:

The Server works as relay station for the [SPRIID](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellberg.spriid&hl=en) app users.

With the SPRIID app you send files to other devices trough this dedicated java Server.

- Everything work trough C2DM(GCM)

- Backend MongoDb databas register users and frindlist's and handle transfer details

For test trying the app, install it, add yourself as friend, send something..*

How can the server pars the `authToken` return with  `getAuthToken()`?
Must my server run some GAE api?
Is the "Federated Login" the way to go and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think i got it working now warning do Im still learning this

In the Nick's sample code above im replacing the

```
accountManager.getAuthToken(account, "ah", false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

with

```
accountManager.getAuthToken(account,"oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", false, new GetAuthTokenCallback(), null);
```

Now i get a Token and can in my chrome browser do:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=ya29.AHeS6ZQpS0T0jipB0grWzuqINDdP98zjj-uljvw1GTR1_2s
```

That will return this json

```
{
 "id": "100864638927226952543326",
 "name": "Billy Bob",
 "given_name": "Billy",
 "family_name": "Bob",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/13444649626952543326",
 "picture": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/--QPesNgxryI/AAAAAeewAAAI/AAAAAAAAAFo/J-LSwl0bcVU/photo.jpg",
 "gender": "male",
 "locale": "us"
}
```

What i wanted was the "id", that is suppose to be unique

Comment: Glad you have something working, but if this is a new question, post it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Not too clear what exactly you are doing, maybe give more details about your server.

Generally, you simply pass the token using your own custom protocol. If you are using ClientLogin tokens, the only way to check if they are valid is to try calling the corresponding Google service (e.g., Calendar) and check if you get a 200 (401 for unauthroized) response. For OAuth tokens, there is an API to validate them.

Also consider using HTTP and use standard authentication protocols.

Comment: That doesn't really say much about the actual implementation and there is no reason whatsoever to be in bold.

Comment: In that Nick's example the accountManager.getAuthToken(..) return a AuthToken that i think i must put into the  "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" to get the Json-userdata `access_token` parameter.. The goal was to get a unique identifier so my users never have to enter/remember password

Comment: What protocol is the Java server running? Where does it run on (your own machine, AWS, GAE, etc.)? Can it connect to arbitrary servers (e.g., Google's).BTW, you need an OAuth2 token for the API you linked.

Comment: In this stage in BETA server run's on my win7 computer at home.
It's an all java.io.InputStream SSLServerSocket not using HTTP. Yes it can be changed to connect to Google and im open for drastic redesigns to adapt to better scalability , that's my goal to learn this to. The reason for the Absens of HTTP is finer grain control over file transfer resuming

Comment: Up till now it's been all about calibrating the file transfer engine and it's time to pull out the user-handling stuff to it's own server. I know HTTP is the way to go here. The MongoDb as backend DB makes everything so easy. Coming from Java learning the Android in a year has been very enriching

Comment: Consider using Google Play Services on the Android side to get an OAuth2 token for the users Google profile and validating this on the server. Of course, you need to make it clear to users why you are using their profile info. Definitely consider HTTP, especially since some mobile operators may block connections to custom ports. http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2012/09/google-play-services-and-oauth-identity.html

Comment: Thanks im on my way, been attending online Google I/O 2012 to learn OAuth2.0 for a few days. I see all examples are tarketing google apis like calender and maps. I only need the client ID since it's a Constant. Can you say something about this, examples not targeting the 3-leg OAuth client,consumer,user. Only need the Constant ID to eliminate the password.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about constant client ID?

Comment: In my below answer, This `"id": "100864638927226952543326"` is suppose to never change even if user change, remove, create new profile email.

Comment: It is likely tied to the particular Google account, and it is doubtful that if you create a new email (== Gmail account) it will stay the same. If you just change your profile info, it will probably stay the same. In any case, if it is not clearly documented, you may not want to rely on it.